# Python Basemap "Assertion failed"

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap

I am using Anaconda 2.1.0 and Basemap installation is successful

```
conda install basemap
conda install gdal
```

I have geos version 3.3.3 and proj4 4.8.0-0. However, I keep getting the following error when I try to project (lat,lon) degrees to a planar:

```
 Assertion failed: (0), function query, file AbstractSTRtree.cpp, line 286.
```

My code looks like this:

```
import shapely.geometry as sg
from pymongo import MongoClient
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

p = Basemap(projection='sinu',lon_0=0,resolution='c')

projected_xy = p(24.4,45.1)
```

Comment: Someone with enough basemap rep might want to make it an actual synoym to matplotlib-basemap. It is already described as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into the same issues when working with geopandas. Again, the order of imports was relevant. In this case, I had to import geopandas after Basemap. My     list of imports looks as follows:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import geopandas as gp
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiPolygon
from shapely.prepared import prep
```

Note that if you are working in a Jupyter notebook your Kernel connection will crash and no information of the error will be given. After using the python shell, the following error was given:

```
Assertion failed: (0), function query, file AbstractSTRtree.cpp, line 285.
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, Basemap has to be imported before shapely.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import shapely.geometry as sg
```

Doing the import the other way around will cause the error.