# Basemap causes python to abort

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I need to map some data points onto a map. I downloaded the basemap module for python to do this. I get the following error message each time I attempt to even make a map. The code I use for this is below. How can I fix this?

The version of geos I am using is 3.4.2, the version of basemap I am using is 1.0.7. The version of python I am using is 2.7. The version of gdal I am using is 1.11.2.

error message:

```
Assertion failed: (0), function query, file AbstractSTRtree.cpp, line 285.
aborted
```

code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

def main():
    map = Basemap(projection = 'cyl', llcrnrlon= -100, llcrnrlat = -18, urcrnrlon =-80, urcrnrlat = 31)
    map.drawcoastlines(linewidth = .01)
    map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
    plot.show()
main()
```

Comment: Apart from the drawboundary, everything works fine. So I think the GEOS package requires some more parent-child relations.
That is also the assertion error:  assert(0); // unsupported childBoundable type

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I don't know what that means nor do I know how to fix it. I googled that to try to understand it. The only results brought me to another set of questions. I tried [one of the solutions](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/288), but that one did not work. @Uvar

Comment: @Uvar do you  meant to say that there are more dependencies that GEOS needs that I don't yet have downloaded?

Comment: Are you sure you are not importing [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) prior to running this script? I get the same exact error if I `import shapely.geometry` first. Strangely, if I import shapely after importing basemap, I don't get the problem. I have all the same versions installed using Homebrew on my OSX 10.10.4 (Yosemite) machine.

Comment: @farenorth I do not import shapely. Do I need to do this? I have it installed on my computer.

Comment: If you're getting the error without then I have a different manifestation of what is probably the same bug. I was asking in case you are using a Python environment that automatically loads shapely before you run this script. If you're not sure you could search the output of `sys.modules.keys()` for the presence of shapely.

Comment: Shapely is based on geos, so I am not surprised there is an interaction here.I'll try to find some time to delve into this further soon. Please be patient with me though. Could you try the result when importing shapely?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I just tried a new import order. I thought I had already tried this, but apparently I had not. Forgive my overlook of this. My new import order is shapely.geometry, matplotlib.pyplot, the basemap, and then numpy. I should say that it runs now, but that it doesn't show any kind of map. I believe this is just my lack of knowledge of basemap now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @K.Shores are you saying you also have to import shapely to generate the error?

Comment: FYI, I once had a bug where if I imported gdal and shapely in the same module I got a segmentation fault. If I switched the order of the imports, no seg fault.

Comment: I'm saying that after I import shapely and arrange the imports correctly, that I no longer have an error. Without importing shapely I get an error. If they are arranged incorrectly I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug was driving me nuts. There are quite a few other SE questions and websites that have a similar issue: [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127636/python-basemap-fails), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675734/python-basemap-assertion-failed), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675734/python-basemap-assertion-failed), but they all recommend importing `mpl_toolkits.Basemap` *before*  `shapely.geometry`. The problem is, this is the import order that *causes* the problem for myself and @K.Shores. If I reverse the import order (shapely first), I don't get the problem.

I think I found a more satisfying fix to this issue [here](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/260). Apparently there is a conflict between the Homebrew GEOS library and one that is bundled with the precompiled shapely wheel. So, to fix the problem, do:

```
$ pip uninstall shapely
$ pip install --no-use-wheel shapely
```

Comment: The --no-use-wheel approach did not work for me but importing shapely first did the trick. Thanks.